# The type 'int' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Range<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

when i try to send parameter of type int it gives me this error
CS0315  The type 'int' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Range'. There is no boxing conversion from 'int' to 'Assignment_17_C__Advanced_1.ISubtractable'.

```
namespace Assignment_17_C__Advanced_1
{
    public interface ISubtractable<T>
    {
        T Subtract(T other);
    }
    public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>,ISubtractable<T>
    {
        private T _min;
        private T _max;


        public Range(T min, T max)
        {
            if (min.CompareTo(max) > 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Minimum value must be less than or equal to maximum value");
            _min = min;
            _max = max;
        }

        public bool IsInRange(T v)
        {
            return v.CompareTo(_min)>0 && v.CompareTo(_max) <= 0;
        }
       
        public T Length()
        {

            T length = _max.Subtract(_min);
            return length;
        }
    }
 internal class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         
             Range<int> range = new Range<int>(10, 20);
             range.IsInRange(20);

         


     }
 }
}
```

Comment: `int` simply does not implement `ISubtractable<T>`. How can it implement such interface if  `int` is a system type and the interface is a custom one? Starting from .NET 7,  `int` it implements `System.Numerics.ISubtractionOperators<T,T,T>`: you can try constraining your `Range<T>` type to such interface.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all: any value for parameter `T` must implement `ISubtractable<T>`, and `int` does not. `int` merely implements `IComparable<T>`, which is only one of the requirements.

Comment: how can i implement subtraction between two generics type without using this interface (ISubtractable)?

Comment: Depending on the .NET version you use, if you use .NET >= 7, you can force type T to implement ISubtractionOperators<T,T,T>, and on it you have method Subtraction, which is implemented by int the way you want it.